# Python - convert list of tuples to a list of int

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have

```
x = [[1], [2, 3], [1, (3, 5)], [(3, 9), 7, 5]]
```

and I want

```
x = [[1], [2, 3], [1, 3, 5], [3, 9, 7, 5]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please share your attempt to achieve the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this through series of for loops.

```
>>> x = [[1], [2, 3], [1, (3, 5)], [(3, 9), 7, 5]]
>>> l = []
>>> for i in x:
        m = []
        for j in i:
            if isinstance(j, tuple):
                m.extend(j)
            else:
                m.append(j)
        l.append(m)


>>> l
[[1], [2, 3], [1, 3, 5], [3, 9, 7, 5]]
```

Comment: thanks but I want a solution wich is general because I can have [[1],[2,((5,6),1)]] and the result must be: [[1],[2,5,6,1]] (so how to make your solution in a recursive form)?

Answer (score -1):

This is a very discouraged approach. Look it as a manifesto against put lots of lambdas, map, reduce inside list comprehensions in a answer to beginner's question.

```
>>> x = [[1], [2, 3], [1, (3, 5)], [(3, 9), 7, 5]]
>>> eval(str(x).replace('(', '').replace(')', ''))
[[1], [2, 3], [1, 3, 5], [3, 9, 7, 5]]
```